# NSURL Bad URL error when using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

Tags: nsurl, nsurlerrordomain

I  concatenated two strings to get a URL, below is the method for concatenating the strings:
The purpose of this is to go from a URL namely:

- `https://vula.uct.ac.za/portal/pda/9f563cb2-24f9-481f-ab2e-631e85c9f3aa/tool-reset/10f71bdb-24b9-4060-bf6d-2c9654253aa3`

to a shorter URL that displays only part of the webpage and is:

- `https://vula.uct.ac.za/portal/tool-reset/10f71bdb-24b9-4060-bf6d-2c9654253aa3`

  ```
  -(NSString *)cropURL:(NSString *)inputURL{
  NSString *outputURL ;
  NSRange match;
  match = [inputURL rangeOfString: @"tool-reset"]; //Gives the index and range of the string "tool-reset"
  int toolLen = match.location+match.length ; //Gives the index after "tool-reset"
  NSString*tempIdentifier = [inputURL substringFromIndex:toolLen] ; //Gets the characters after "tool-reset"
  NSString *firstURL = @"https://vula.uct.ac.za/portal/tool-reset" ; //First part of URL
  NSMutableArray *concatURL = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2] ; // Array to concat firstURL and tempIdentifier
  [concatURL addObject:(NSString *)firstURL] ;
  [concatURL addObject:(NSString *) tempIdentifier] ;
  outputURL = [concatURL componentsJoinedByString:@""] ; //Concatenatd to outputURL
  outputURL = [outputURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ; //Encoding
  return outputURL ;
  ```

  }

*Note that the website requires the user to log in, this is done earlier and these methods are only called once login is successful.

I sent this concatenated URL to the connection method with a GET and I get the error below:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x1d51f7d0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1e547980 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

The unconcatenated URL doesn't have this problem though.

The URL in question is:

```
https://vula.uct.ac.za/portal/tool-reset/10f71bdb-24b9-4060-bf6d-2c9654253aa3
```

the URL is correct and has been tested. (Again, note that the site requires you to log in)

I did use:

```
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
```

before sending it to the the connection, but I still get the same error.

All my other links work, the only links that don't work are the ones that were concatenated. These concatenated strings do work in a normal web browser.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: @ali-hen can you paste your concatenation code.

Comment: @ali-hen Did you convert the string to NSURL format?

Comment: @icodebuster yes I did, in the connection method at the request I used ... initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:currentURL] ...
Where currentURL is the URL in question.

Comment: @ali-hen can you post a sample string that you are passing to the cropUrl function

Comment: @icodebuster the sample string is the first URL in the question above:
_https://vula.uct.ac.za/portal/pda/9f563cb2-24f9-481f-ab2e-631e85c9f3aa/tool-reset/10f71bdb-24b9-4060-bf6d-2c9654253aa3_

Comment: This is some pretty nasty code! Take a step back, and figure what it is you're actually trying to achieve. My guess is you want "to append the last path component of one URL (`10f71bdb-24b9-4060-bf6d-2c9654253aa3`) onto another URL (`https://vula.uct.ac.za/portal/tool-reset`)". Does that sound about right?

Comment: @MikeAbdullah, Thanks for explaining it like that. Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. Guess it's always good to get another perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this then:

```
NSURL *input = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vula.uct.ac.za/portal/pda/9f563cb2-24f9-481f-ab2e-631e85c9f3aa/tool-reset/10f71bdb-24b9-4060-bf6d-2c9654253aa3"];

NSString *identifier = input.lastPathComponent;

NSURL *base = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vula.uct.ac.za/portal/tool-reset/"];

NSURL *output = [base URLByAppendingPathComponent:identifier];
```